# iOS Xcode -Editing Storyboard Objects Results In View Controllers Scenes Duplicating Another Scene Then Xcode Crashing

Tags: xcode, crash, storyboard

I'm working on **Sierra version 10.12.6 and Xcode 8.3**, I have 3 scenes in Storyboard that are all connected to one another via push segues.

The 1st scene has a tableView and a cell with an imageView and 2 labels.

The 2nd scene has a tableView and a cell with an imageView and 4 labels.

The 3rd scenes has a tableView with a cell that contains 3 labels and a collectionView with a cell that has an imageView.

When I try to make adjustments to the 3rd scene the 1st and 2nd scene automatically updates to match the same exact elements that are on the 3rd scene and then Xcode crashes.

The problem only happens when I try to make adjustments to the 3rd scene.

On the 3rd scene I tried to disconnect all the objects from it's view controller and then make the adjustments but the 1st and 2nd scene still duplicates everything, Xcode crashes and when it reopens all of the connections are still alive (as if I never disconnected them).

I then disconnected the segues between the scenes but the same exact problem occurs -once I make an adjustment to the 3rd scene the other two scenes update to match and then there is a crash.

After the crash once I open the project everything is back to normal.

*The 3rd scene is the all the way to the right and has pink inside of it:*

**Before I make an adjustment on the 3rd scene:**
[image]

**After I make an adjustment to the 3rd scene:**
[image]

I tried cleaning the project with a deep clean, a regular clean, deleting derived data, completely uninstalled Xcode then reinstalled it again but the problem still occurs.

Why are the other 2 scenes automatically updating to match the 3rd scene?

[image]

Here are the crash logs:

> Process:               Xcode [84727] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:               8.3 (12169) Build Info:
>   IDEFrameworks-12169000000000000~2 Code Type:             X86-64
>   (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0iag.png) Responsible:           Xcode
>   [84727] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2017-08-01 10:01:54.643 -0400 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:
>   20134940-2FA2-50E1-5E8E-640EC65140FA
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       3E6A13DD-A904-4D70-8D26-BA158BDA1C5E
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 190000 seconds Time Since Wake:       6500
>   seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 8E162 ASSERTION
>   FAILURE in
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-12086/InterfaceBuilder/Autolayout/IBCocoaTouchAutolayoutArbitrationUnit.m:259
>
> Details:  A method claimed to have failed but provided no error!
>
> Object:   
>   Method:   -engineEvaluatedConstantValuesOfConstraints:error: Thread:
>   {number = 1, name = main} Hints:
>   Backtrace:   0   -[IDEAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in IDEKit)   1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)   2
>   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)   3   -[IBCocoaTouchAutolayoutArbitrationUnit engineEvaluatedConstantValuesOfConstraints:error:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   4
>   __IBEnumerateEngineEvaluatedConstantsForConstraintsWithBlockAndFallbackBlock_block_invoke
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   5   __NSDictionaryEnumerate (in
>   CoreFoundation)   6
>   IBEnumerateEngineEvaluatedConstantsForConstraintsWithBlockAndFallbackBlock
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   7   -[IBViewEditor
>   _populateEngineEvaluatedConstantsByConstraint:andPopulateConstraintsByAbstraction:forDrawingConstraintAbstractions:]
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   8   -[IBViewEditor
>   updateConstraintDrawablesAndGuideLinesForOrderedConstraintAbstractions:]
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   9   -[IBViewEditor
>   pushOrderedConstraintAbstractionsToDraw:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit) 
>   10   -[IBViewEditor updateConstraintsForViews] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  11   -[IBViewEditor
>   updateConstraintVisibilityBasedUponSelection] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  12   -[IBViewEditor
>   selectionOwner:didSelect:andDeselect:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  13
>   -[IBSelectionOwner didSelect:andDeselect:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  14   -[IBSelectionOwner primitiveUpdateSelection:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  15   -[IBSelectionOwner
>   selectObjects:byExtending:andToggling:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit) 
>   16   -[IBCanvasViewController selectObjectsInEditor:scrollSettings:]
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  17   -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController
>   dragTarget:didAcceptDraggedObjects:fromDragInfo:context:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  18   -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController
>   performDragOperation:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  19
>   -[IBEditorCanvasFrame performDragOperation:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  20   DVTTrackDragging (in DVTKit)  21
>   -[DVTDragManager dragImage:at:mouseDownEvent:pasteboard:allowedOperations:source:slideBack:draggingSourceContext:]
>   (in DVTKit)  22   -[DVTDragManager
>   dragImage:at:offset:mouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:pasteboard:allowedOperations:source:slideBack:draggingSourceContext:]
>   (in DVTKit)  23   __151-[IBEditorCanvasFrameController
>   dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:editor:draggingSourceContext:]_block_invoke
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  24   -[IBDocument
>   disableSavingWithError:whileRunningBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
>   25   -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController
>   dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:editor:draggingSourceContext:]
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  26   -[IBViewEditorCanvasFrameController
>   dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:editor:draggingSourceContext:]
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  27   __113-[IBEditor
>   dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:dragContext:]_block_invoke
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  28   -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager
>   delayAutolayoutStatusUpdatingDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  29 
>   -[IBDocument delayAutolayoutStatusUpdatingDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  30   -[IBEditor
>   dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:dragContext:]
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  31   -[IBUITableViewCellContentViewEditor
>   dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:dragContext:]
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)  32   __61-[IBViewEditor
>   dragChildViews:withMouseDown:andMouseDragged:]_block_invoke (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  33   -[IBViewEditor
>   drawBordersOnDraggedViewsWhilePerformingBlock:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  34   -[IBViewEditor
>   dragChildViews:withMouseDown:andMouseDragged:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  35   -[IBViewEditor
>   dragSelectedViewsWithMouseDown:andMouseDragged:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  36   -[IBViewEditor interceptMouseDragged:]
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  37   -[IBViewEditor interceptEvent:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  38   -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController
>   sendEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  39
>   -[IBViewEditorCanvasFrameController sendEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  40   -[IBEditorCanvasFrame mouseDragged:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  41   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting)
>   _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)  42   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)  43   -[IDEWorkspaceWindow sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)  44   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)  45   -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)  46   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)  47   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)  48   start (in
>   libdyld.dylib)   abort() called
>
> Application Specific Signatures:
>   __localError
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000111cf2d42 __pthread_kill + 10
>   1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc8457 pthread_kill +
>   90 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00007fffc8149420 abort + 129 3
>   com.apple.dt.IDEKit               0x000000010fd1c1de
>   +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:]
>   + 1378 4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit            0x000000010fd1c864 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   + 1175 5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x000000010e619a8c _DVTAssertionHandler + 375 6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation        0x000000010e619d1d _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 369 7
>   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000125297bdb
>   -[IBCocoaTouchAutolayoutArbitrationUnit engineEvaluatedConstantValuesOfConstraints:error:] + 1175 8
>   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit   0x00000001238e4f50
>   __IBEnumerateEngineEvaluatedConstantsForConstraintsWithBlockAndFallbackBlock_block_invoke
>   + 557 9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffb237f7ec __NSDictionaryEnumerate + 844 10  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit    0x00000001238e4a1c
>   IBEnumerateEngineEvaluatedConstantsForConstraintsWithBlockAndFallbackBlock
>   + 688 11  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000123ab8017 -[IBViewEditor _populateEngineEvaluatedConstantsByConstraint:andPopulateConstraintsByAbstraction:forDrawingConstraintAbstractions:]
>   + 393 12  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000123ab8530 -[IBViewEditor updateConstraintDrawablesAndGuideLinesForOrderedConstraintAbstractions:]
>   + 339 13  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000123ab9d4d -[IBViewEditor pushOrderedConstraintAbstractionsToDraw:] + 371 14  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit   0x0000000123aba891
>   -[IBViewEditor updateConstraintsForViews] + 2475 15  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit  0x0000000123abb77d
>   -[IBViewEditor updateConstraintVisibilityBasedUponSelection] + 2620 16  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit   0x0000000123aa7657
>   -[IBViewEditor selectionOwner:didSelect:andDeselect:] + 227 17  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit   0x00000001239ea5a7
>   -[IBSelectionOwner didSelect:andDeselect:] + 172 18  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit  0x00000001239ea7b9
>   -[IBSelectionOwner primitiveUpdateSelection:] + 487 19  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit   0x00000001239ea8c9
>   -[IBSelectionOwner selectObjects:byExtending:andToggling:] + 67 20  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit   0x000000012371718c
>   -[IBCanvasViewController selectObjectsInEditor:scrollSettings:] + 3419 21  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit    0x0000000123854715
>   -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController dragTarget:didAcceptDraggedObjects:fromDragInfo:context:] + 542 22 
>   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit   0x0000000123854a74
>   -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController performDragOperation:] + 282 23  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit  0x00000001238481ed
>   -[IBEditorCanvasFrame performDragOperation:] + 79 24  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010ec83772 DVTTrackDragging +
>   12343 25  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010ec806ce
>   -[DVTDragManager dragImage:at:mouseDownEvent:pasteboard:allowedOperations:source:slideBack:draggingSourceContext:]
>   + 150 26  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010ec84798 -[DVTDragManager dragImage:at:offset:mouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:pasteboard:allowedOperations:source:slideBack:draggingSourceContext:]
>   + 138 27  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000012384c7a7 __151-[IBEditorCanvasFrameController dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:editor:draggingSourceContext:]_block_invoke
>   + 114 28  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000123797604 -[IBDocument disableSavingWithError:whileRunningBlock:] + 107 29  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit    0x000000012384c5d6
>   -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:editor:draggingSourceContext:]
>   + 693 30  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000123ac5825 -[IBViewEditorCanvasFrameController dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:editor:draggingSourceContext:]
>   + 219 31  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000012383f622 __113-[IBEditor dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:dragContext:]_block_invoke
>   + 844 32  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x00000001237f80ee -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager delayAutolayoutStatusUpdatingDuring:] + 31 33  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x00000001237e151e
>   -[IBDocument delayAutolayoutStatusUpdatingDuring:] + 79 34  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit   0x000000012383f183 -[IBEditor
>   dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:dragContext:]
>   + 432 35  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration   0x00000001253d71d9
>   -[IBUITableViewCellContentViewEditor dragObjects:withImage:inMouseDownEvent:mouseDraggedEvent:imageLocation:allowedOperations:dragContext:]
>   + 341 36  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000123aa9988 __61-[IBViewEditor dragChildViews:withMouseDown:andMouseDragged:]_block_invoke + 109 37 
>   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit   0x0000000123aa8f84
>   -[IBViewEditor drawBordersOnDraggedViewsWhilePerformingBlock:] + 28 38  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit   0x0000000123aa94a7
>   -[IBViewEditor dragChildViews:withMouseDown:andMouseDragged:] + 1168 39  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit  0x0000000123aa8fee
>   -[IBViewEditor dragSelectedViewsWithMouseDown:andMouseDragged:] + 96 40  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit  0x0000000123ab2fcf
>   -[IBViewEditor interceptMouseDragged:] + 842 41  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit  0x0000000123ab386e
>   -[IBViewEditor interceptEvent:] + 634 42  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000012385b86e
>   -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController sendEvent:] + 1826 43  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit    0x0000000123ac5734
>   -[IBViewEditorCanvasFrameController sendEvent:] + 349 44  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000123846723
>   -[IBEditorCanvasFrame mouseDragged:] + 79 45  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffb07713ca -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting)
>   _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 4340 46  com.apple.AppKit                 0x00007fffb076ff0a -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 541 47 
>   com.apple.dt.IDEKit               0x000000010fd61e58 -[IDEWorkspaceWindow
>   sendEvent:] + 154 48  com.apple.AppKit
>     0x00007fffb05f4681 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1145 49 
>   com.apple.dt.IDEKit               0x000000010fdab177 -[IDEApplication
>   sendEvent:] + 926 50  com.apple.AppKit
>     0x00007fffafe6f427 -[NSApplication run] + 1002 51  com.apple.AppKit
>     0x00007fffafe39e0e NSApplicationMain + 1237 52  libdyld.dylib
>     0x0000000111c9a235 start + 1
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000111ceb34a
>   mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x0000000111cea797 mach_msg + 55 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fffb2382874 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffb2381cf1 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1361 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fffb2381544
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420 5   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fffb3db2252 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
>   6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase         0x000000011bc6b143
>   +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 217 7   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fffb3dc28ad __NSThread__start**
>   + 1243 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start + 286 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000111dc508d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000111ceb34a
>   mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x0000000111cea797 mach_msg + 55 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fffb2382874 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffb2381cf1 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1361 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fffb2381544
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420 5   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fffb3db2252 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
>   6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase         0x000000011bc79df1
>   -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 1454 7   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fffb3dc28ad __NSThread__start**
>   + 1243 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start + 286 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000111dc508d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x0000000111cf2eb6 __select + 10 1   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fffb23bd939 __CFSocketManager + 729 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180
>   3   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start +
>   286 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc508d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000111cf2bf2
>   __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000111dc67fa _pthread_cond_wait + 712 2   libc++.1.dylib
>     0x00007fffc6c514cd
>   std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock&) + 47 3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore         0x00007fffb53b043c void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait >(std::__1::unique_lock&) + 108 4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore       0x00007fffb53b03bb
>   bmalloc::AsyncTask::threadRunLoop() + 155 5
>   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fffb53b028d
>   bmalloc::AsyncTask::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::AsyncTask*) + 29 6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore
>
>     0x00007fffb53b053d void*
>   std::__1::__thread_proxy*),
>   bmalloc::AsyncTask*>
>
> > (void*) + 93 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start + 286 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> >       0x0000000111dc508d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 5:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 
>     0x0000000111ceb34a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x0000000111cea797 mach_msg + 55 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fffb2382874 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffb2381cf1 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1361 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fffb2381544
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420 5   com.apple.CFNetwork
>
>     0x000000011152a734 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] +
>   313 6   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fffb3dc28ad
>   __NSThread__start** + 1243 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start + 286 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000111dc508d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 6:: com.apple.NSEventThread 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x0000000111ceb34a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x0000000111cea797 mach_msg + 55 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fffb2382874 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212 3
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffb2381cf1 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1361 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fffb2381544
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420 5   com.apple.AppKit
>     0x00007fffaffc7f02 _NSEventThread + 205 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start + 286 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000111dc508d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 7:: DYMobileDeviceManager 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x0000000111ceb34a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x0000000111cea797 mach_msg + 55 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fffb2382874 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fffb2381cf1 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1361 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fffb2381544
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420 5   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fffb3db2252 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
>   6   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fffb3db212a
>   -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76 7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation   0x00000001272f525d
>   -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134 8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffb3dc28ad __NSThread__start**
>   + 1243 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start + 286 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000111dc508d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 8: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000111dc5070
>   start_wqthread + 0 1   ???
>     0x000070000c38db80 0 + 123145507363712
>
> Thread 9: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000111cf2bf2
>   **psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000111dc67fa _pthread_cond_wait + 712 2
>
>   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore      0x0000000120ef3822 -[XCBlockQueue
>   _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 594 3   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fffb3dc28ad __NSThread__start** + 1243 4
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180
>   5   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start +
>   286 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc508d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 10: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000111cf2bf2
>   **psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000111dc67fa _pthread_cond_wait + 712 2
>
>   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore      0x0000000120ef3822 -[XCBlockQueue
>   _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 594 3   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fffb3dc28ad __NSThread__start** + 1243 4
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180
>   5   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start +
>   286 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc508d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 11: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000111cf2bf2
>   **psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000111dc67fa _pthread_cond_wait + 712 2
>
>   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore      0x0000000120ef3822 -[XCBlockQueue
>   _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 594 3   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fffb3dc28ad __NSThread__start** + 1243 4
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180
>   5   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start +
>   286 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc508d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 12: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000111dc5070
>   start_wqthread + 0 1   ???
>     0x0000000000000010 0 + 16
>
> Thread 13: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000111cf344e
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc548e _pthread_wqthread + 1023 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc507d start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 14: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000111dc5070
>   start_wqthread + 0 1   ???
>     0x00007fc08b23c020 0 + 140464944824352
>
> Thread 15: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000111cf344e
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc548e _pthread_wqthread + 1023 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc507d start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 16: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000111cf2f46
>   __semwait_signal + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fffc816ab72 nanosleep + 199 2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication
>     0x00007fffbe4f62ed cleaner_thread_main(void*) + 42 3
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc593b _pthread_body + 180
>   4   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc5887 _pthread_start +
>   286 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000111dc508d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
>   0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff51855448 
>   rdx: 0x0000000000000000   rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi:
>   0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff51855470  rsp: 0x00007fff51855448
>   r8: 0x00007fc09a5058e0   r9: 0x0000000110411897  r10:
>   0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206   r12: 0x00007fffc77c8410 
>   r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000111dcd3c0  r15:
>   0x00007fc0a096d640   rip: 0x0000000111cf2d42  rfl: 0x0000000000000206 
>   cr2: 0x00007fffd1019128    Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:
>   0x02000148 Trap Number:     133

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is crashing because of the the IBCocoaTouchAutolayoutArbitrationUnit.m file in your library/caches folder. According to this [link](https://macpaw.com/how-to/clear-cache-on-mac), you can just delete the files in your library/caches folder (don't delete the folder itself) and you should be fine. That should fix the problem. But to play it on the safe side, you probably should move this file to another location instead of deleting. Also try opening your workspace in Xcode 9 beta to see if it crashes the same way with the same error message.